# VBA to shift formula reference down one row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a massive file, that compares year/year data.

Every week I need to update a formula in the file to move down a row. I want to make a command button to update these formulas.

Here is a simple example

cell c800 contains:     =((C235-C229)/C229)*100

I would like to click the button to make the cell update to 
          =((C236-C330)/C330)*100

Can anyone help me out here? is this possible? I've been looking all over for this and can't find anything.

thanks

Comment: is that because there are new values added and the last line with values goes from C229 to C330?

Comment: here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765464/how-to-get-the-last-and-second-from-last-non-empty-field-in-google-spreadsheet/43765682#43765682  if it had been for Excel I would have marked as duplicate.

Comment: I tried index/match but it doesn't work since there are other values below that cell (and formula) It unfortunately needs to be cell specific.  I have a formula that is currently working, that utilizes offset and direct precedents - but I'm not sure how to set that up for this complicated of a formula.

Comment: is there any correlation to the weeknumber and the row?  Or would you be willing to put one or the other row number in the sheet somewhere?  Then we can reference that cell in the formula, so you only need to change the number in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Enter this formula in C800 and it will always capture any newly added lines of data.

```
=(INDEX(C5:C799,MATCH(1E+99,C5:C779,1))-INDEX(C5:C799,MATCH(1E+99,C5:C779,1)-6))/INDEX(C5:C799,MATCH(1E+99,C5:C779,1)-6)*100
```

*assumes first data point is in C5. Change as needed*

This works because `MATCH(1E+99,C5:C799,-1)` finds the last numerical value in the column.

Comment: This doesn't work for the data set, unfortunately there are other formulas listed in the column. It needs to be a specific cell reference,

Comment: @AmandaHu can you change the `C799` reference to whatever the last possible cell will / can be? Conceptually it should work as long as you tighten range. Unless you insert stuff manually (or through code) each time which adjusts ranges.

Answer (score -1):

there is a function to do that, as if the cell containing the formula was copied somewhere else and the cell references in the formula were shifted/moved:

```
strFormulaMoved$ = Application.ConvertFormula(Application.ConvertFormula(Selection.Formula, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, , Range("C800")), XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, , Range("C800").Offset(1, 0))
```